# Web service (ASP.NET) and android application (API) talkability

Tags: android, asp.net, ajax, api, rest

I'm researching a side project I'm interested in at the moment which is having an attachment to an android phone that can scan fingerprints and enrol/verify them on an online database.

I'd like to have a log in system so the user could access their database and I've already scoped out a good open source recognition program called Source AFIS.

I don't have many problems writing the android application or created a program using Source AFIS, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around the connection of the two.

From researching I think the best way to do it is by building a REST API for the app, but since I want the web service part to run a program and return the result, I was leaning towards writing it in ASP.NET AJAX for the web service, is it possible to still build a REST API that can easily interact with the web service if this is the case?

Comment: You can use the new [ASP .NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) to easily build RESTful applications.

Comment: Yes, you can build a web api service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Android app can make a HTTP request just like a web browser, JavaScript in a web browser, and any other applications.  You'll just need to declare a permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Check out the docs for [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), which is the recommended class for Android 2.3 and up.  You can use this to make GET and POST requests to any URL, including your ASP.NET back end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ksoap` library for this purpose,more help at http://www.sacoskun.com/2010/02/consuming-net-web-services-via-ksoap_07.html